# Is it a coincidence that pKw = 14.00 at SATP?

Tags: acid-base, equilibrium, water

High school chemistry student here. For our purposes in class for studying acids and bases, we are taught that $\text{p}K_\text{w}=14.00$, which is central for many of our calculations. I assume this is the value for room temperature and standard pressure.

However, it seems awfully suspicious that the negative $\log$ of an equilibrium constant should turn out to be a whole number. Is this just a useful coincidence? Or have scientists pulled some clever tricks, ex. by defining "room temperature" to be the temperature such that $\text{p}K_\text{w}=14.0000...$?

Comment: Pure coincidence. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-ionization_of_water#Dependence_on_temperature.2C_pressure_and_ionic_strength

Comment: @Zhe I don't think it's *exactly* $1.0 \times 10^{-14}$

Comment: @PrittBalagopal That's exactly what the link indicates. I'm not claiming that it is. Though I can see my wording is not great here...